# Laravel 5.2 Many to Many query relationship with where clause

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a little problem, I have a table with **Movies** and another with **Genres** ex: Action, Adventure etc...

*Table names:*

- movies
- movie_genre
- genres

I want to fetch all the Movies with the selected Genre ex: **Action**

```
$movies = Movie::with('genres')
            ->when($genre, function ($query) use ($genre) {
                        return $query->where('genres.id', $genre->id);
                    })
            ->paginate(20);
```

This php code doesn't work, how can I make it work?

PS: The genre is transfered from the view by $_GET['genre'] and stocked in the variable $genre.

***Edit after the answer of @Shane and @Marcin Nabiałek :***

The relationship is set in the models and when I use your code directly like this:

```
Movie::with('genres', 'countries', 'type')
            ->when($type, function ($query) use ($type) {
                        return $query->where('medias.type_id', $type->id);
                    })
            ->whereHas('genres', function ($query) use ($genre) {
                 return $query->where('genres.id', $genre->id);
               })
            ->paginate(20);
```

it work perfectly, but with the when() function it dosn't. I have to use the `when()` to make the condition work only if there is a genre selected by the user.

Comment: Are you getting multiple values in `$_GET['genre']` or single value ?

Comment: Try `whereHas`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: I get only one value with the `$_GET['genre']`. the `whereHas` work perfectly but not with the `when()` and I use it to make the condition work only if there is a genre selected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `whereHas` to get all movies that are assigned to given genre:

```
$movies = Movie::with('genres')
            ->when($genre, function ($query) use ($genre) {
                  $query->whereHas('genres', function($q) use ($genre) {
                     return $query->where('id', $genre->id);
                   });                                  
            })->paginate(20);
```

In case $genre is only id and not model, you should rather use:

```
 return $query->where('id', $genre);
```

and in case it's an array (user is allowed to choose multiple genres), you should use:

```
 return $query->whereIn('id', (array) $genre);
```

Comment: when I use your code without the `->when()` and use it directly like this:

`$movies = Movie::with('genres', 'countries', 'type')
                ->when($type, function ($query) use ($type) {
                            return $query->where('medias.type_id', $type->id);
                        })
                >whereHas('genres', function ($query) use ($genre) {
                     return $query->where('genres.id', $genre->id);
                    })
                ->paginate(20);`

it work perfectly, but with the when() function it dosn't

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `when` function. I use `whereHas`:

```
$movies = Movie::whereHas('genres', function ($query) use ($genre) {
    $query->where('id', $genre->id);
})->with('genres')->get();
```

Also, is `$genre` the model or the ID? You mentioned it was received from `$_GET` which would mean it would be an ID probably.

I think a better solution would be to use your relationship function in the `Genre` model to get them:

```
$movies = Genre::find($genre_id)->movies;
```

Comment: $genre is the model because i fetch the id from the database and stock it in the variable $genre.

Comment: @Chidox I would use the second example. Replace `$genre_id` with `$genre->id`. You just need to make sure you have the relationship set up in the `Genre` model: `public function movies() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie'); }`

Comment: The relationship is set in the models and when I use your code directly like this: $movies = Movie::with('genres', 'countries', 'type') ->when($type, function ($query) use ($type) { return $query->where('medias.type_id', $type->id); }) >whereHas('genres', function ($query) use ($genre) { return $query->where('genres.id', $genre->id); }) ->paginate(20); it work perfectly, but with the when() function it dosn't. I have to use the `when()` to make the condition work only if there is a genre selected by the user.

Comment: @Chidox If the genre isn't supplied by the user in the `$_GET` variable, what should it do?

Comment: an error appear _Undifined variable : $genre_ something like this.